# phpMyAdmin is displaying PHP code instead of executing it

Tags: server, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04 with:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

after installation, localhost/phpmyadmin shows a not found error page.

I used this code for solving this issue:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

But localhost/phpmyadmin return php code as text.

See the screen-shot:

[image: pic]

Where is my problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by __return php code__ ?

Comment: @George Hi, i add image issue page

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed PHP, or you didn't setup a way for Apache to interface with PHP. See for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/846860/cant-run-php-file/846870#846870

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck thank you for answer, but I din't notice for this example, please help me...

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Not show phpmyadmin page ! php 7 is install.

Comment: You need to setup a way for Apache to interface with PHP. There are several ways to do so, each has its own advantages and disadvantages. Please describe your server and what you're using it for. Are we talking about a local playground for yourself only, behind a firewall? Are we talking about a public server with high traffic websites on it?